# Implementação algoritmo Dijkstra em Python

Tags: python, grafo

Estou implementando o algoritmo de Dijkstra em um grafo, porém ele me retorna apenas a primeira chamada à função. Mesmo que eu chame novamente não há retorno, alguém sabe dizer o motivo?
Segue o código:

```
def Dijkstra2(self, source, dest):
    shortestDist = {}
    predecessor = {}
    infinity = float('inf')
    path = []

    for node in self.graph:
        shortestDist[node] = infinity

    shortestDist[source] = 0

    while self.graph:
        minNode = None
        for node in self.graph:
            if minNode is None:
                minNode = node
            elif shortestDist[node] < shortestDist[minNode]:
                minNode = node

        for childNode, weight in self.graph[minNode]:
            if (self.hasVertex(childNode) == True):
                weight = int(weight)
                if weight + shortestDist[minNode] < shortestDist[childNode]:
                    shortestDist[childNode] = shortestDist[minNode] + weight
                    predecessor[childNode] = minNode

        self.graph.pop(minNode)

    currentNode = dest

    while currentNode != source:
        try:
            path.insert(0, currentNode)
            currentNode = predecessor[currentNode]
        except KeyError:
            print('Path not reachable')
            break

    path.insert(0, source)

    if (shortestDist[dest] != infinity):

        print('Shortest distance between ', source, ' and ', dest, 'is ' + str(shortestDist[dest]))
        print('The paths is ' + str(path))

    return path
```

o grafo:

grafo = {james: {(larry, 2), (liam, 3)}; larry: {(james, 1), (paul, 3)}; paul: {(jim, 2)}}

Quando executo:

```
grafo.Dijkstra2('james', 'paul')
grafo.Dijkstra2('james', 'liam')
```

retorna:

```
Shortest distance between james and paul is 5
The path is [james, larry, paul]
```

Mas a outra chamada não executa. Onde está o erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que seja quando você executa `self.graph.pop(minNode)` que esta removendo o nodo do grafo, assim na segunda execução o grafo esta vazio e acaba não retornando nada.

Pode fazer um teste colocando um `if` no inicio do método que imprima algo se o grafo esta vazio.